# How to remove leading zeros from alphanumeric text?

Tags: java, string, alphanumeric

I've seen questions on how to prefix zeros here in SO. But not the other way!

Can you guys suggest me how to remove the leading zeros in alphanumeric text? Are there any built-in APIs or do I need to write a method to trim the leading zeros?

Example:

```
01234 converts to 1234
0001234a converts to 1234a
001234-a converts to 1234-a
101234 remains as 101234
2509398 remains as 2509398
123z remains as 123z
000002829839 converts to 2829839
```

Answer (score 767, accepted):

Regex is the best tool for the job; what it should be depends on the problem specification. The following removes leading zeroes, but leaves one if necessary (i.e. it wouldn't just turn `"0"` to a blank string).

```
s.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "")
```

The `^` anchor will make sure that the `0+` being matched is at the beginning of the input. The `(?!$)` negative lookahead ensures that not the entire string will be matched.

Test harness:

```
String[] in = {
    "01234",         // "[1234]"
    "0001234a",      // "[1234a]"
    "101234",        // "[101234]"
    "000002829839",  // "[2829839]"
    "0",             // "[0]"
    "0000000",       // "[0]"
    "0000009",       // "[9]"
    "000000z",       // "[z]"
    "000000.z",      // "[.z]"
};
for (String s : in) {
    System.out.println("[" + s.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "") + "]");
}
```

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

  - [repetitions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), and [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)
- [`String.replaceFirst(String regex)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Thank you. And you have tested ruthlessly ;) Great !! +1 for the tests.

Comment: replaceFirst is not a function.  Is it not available in FireFox?

Comment: @Greg: This question is about Java, not JavaScript. Java SE has had the method [String.replaceFirst()](http://bit.ly/MCZfrt) since version 1.4.

Comment: How about below 1.4 ?

Comment: adding trim() to s.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "") (ie. s.trim().replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "") will help in removing padded spaces!

Comment: isn't regex a bit expensive for such a simple task?

Comment: finest answer,excelent

Comment: This does not work in Kotlin, you need to be explicit about the Regex `.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)".toRegex(), "")`

Comment: for kotlin it is more clear to use: `yourString.trimStart('0')`

Comment: yourString.trimStart('0') removes all zeros at the first position from a string even the string "0" will get replaced by an empty string. If you want to keep  a string like "0" use @mkabatek's Answer : .replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)".toRegex(), "")

Comment: How can this answer be modified so that it leaves a single zero before the decimal point, like `0.5` instead of `.5`?

Answer (score 171):

You can use the [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) class from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) like this:

```
StringUtils.stripStart(yourString,"0");
```

Comment: Does this have a problem with "0" alone? @Hamilton Rodrigues

Comment: If using this on "0" alone, it gives back "". So care if this is not the desired effect required.

Comment: Upvoted cause it works for the use cases in the question asked. Helped me here too for a quick solution. Thx!

Answer (score 42):

If you are using Kotlin This is the only code that you need:

```
yourString.trimStart('0')
```

Answer (score 40):

How about the regex way:

```
String s = "001234-a";
s = s.replaceFirst ("^0*", "");
```

The `^` anchors to the start of the string (I'm assuming from context your strings are not multi-line here, otherwise you may need to look into `\A` for start of input rather than start of line). The `0*` means zero or more `0` characters (you *could* use `0+` as well). The `replaceFirst` just replaces all those `0` characters at the start with nothing.

And if, like Vadzim, your definition of leading zeros doesn't include turning `"0"` (or `"000"` or similar strings) into an empty string (a rational enough expectation), simply put it back if necessary:

```
String s = "00000000";
s = s.replaceFirst ("^0*", "");
if (s.isEmpty()) s = "0";
```

Comment: It has problem with "0" alone.

Answer (score 30):

A clear way without any need of regExp and any external libraries.

```
public static String trimLeadingZeros(String source) {
    for (int i = 0; i < source.length(); ++i) {
        char c = source.charAt(i);
        if (c != '0') {
            return source.substring(i);
        }
    }
    return ""; // or return "0";
}
```

Comment: Although your check for space isn't according to the question, nevertheless I think your answer would execute the quickest.

Comment: @JohnFowler 10x for the catch, fixed after 2+ years

Comment: And the method needs a return at the end if the loop finds only zeros. return ""; or return "0"; if you want at least one zero

Comment: @slipperyseal I left it open so that you can change it based on your needs but since people tend to copy/paste, it is not a bad idea to always have a default behaviour. thanks for the comment

Answer (score 15):

To go with thelost's Apache Commons answer: using [guava-libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) (Google's general-purpose Java utility library which I would argue should now be on the classpath of any non-trivial Java project), this would use [CharMatcher](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html):

```
CharMatcher.is('0').trimLeadingFrom(inputString);
```

Comment: +1, the correct answer for any project using Guava. (And now in 2012 that *should* mean pretty much any Java project.)

Comment: @Cowan 
 
Does this have a problem with "0" alone? Will CharMatcher.is('0').trimLeadingFrom("0"); Return the "0" or empty String?

Comment: @PhoonOne: I just tested this; it returns the empty string.

Answer (score 14):

You could just do:
`String s = Integer.valueOf("0001007").toString();`

Comment: Won't handle alphanumeric.

Comment: It will also fail if the value is too big for Integer like "00087878787878787878"

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
String x = "00123".replaceAll("^0*", ""); // -> 123
```

Answer (score 5):

Use Apache Commons [`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) class:

```
StringUtils.strip(String str, String stripChars);
```

Comment: WARNING! This will strip leading and ending zeroes, which may not be what you want.

Comment: You can strip only leading zeroes using StringUtils.stripStart().

Answer (score 2):

Using Regexp with groups:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(0*)(.*)");
String result = "";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
if (matcher.matches())
{
      // first group contains 0, second group the remaining characters
      // 000abcd - > 000, abcd
      result = matcher.group(2);
}

return result;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using regex as some of the answers suggest is a good way to do that. If you don't want to use regex then you can use this code:

```
String s = "00a0a121";

while(s.length()>0 && s.charAt(0)=='0')
{
   s = s.substring(1); 
}
```

Comment: This could create a lot of `String`... use [magiccrafter approch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7089841/4391450) instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you (like me) need to remove all the leading zeros from each "word" in a string, you can modify @polygenelubricants' answer to the following:

```
String s = "003 d0g 00ss 00 0 00";
s.replaceAll("\\b0+(?!\\b)", "");
```

which results in:

```
3 d0g ss 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using kotlin it is easy

```
value.trimStart('0')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is so easy to do that. You can just loop over the string from the start and removing zeros until you found a not zero char.

```
int lastLeadZeroIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
  char c = str.charAt(i);
  if (c == '0') {
    lastLeadZeroIndex = i;
  } else {
    break;
  }
}

str = str.subString(lastLeadZeroIndex+1, str.length());
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using `Regex` or `substring()` function on `String` which will be inefficient -

```
public static String removeZero(String str){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(str);
        while (sb.length()>1 && sb.charAt(0) == '0')
            sb.deleteCharAt(0);
        return sb.toString();  // return in String
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `"^0*(.*)"` to `"$1"` with regex

Comment: The only issue I see here is this might replace a lone zero '0' to a blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
       String s="0000000000046457657772752256266542=56256010000085100000";      
    String removeString="";

    for(int i =0;i<s.length();i++){
      if(s.charAt(i)=='0')
        removeString=removeString+"0";
      else 
        break;
    }

    System.out.println("original string - "+s);

    System.out.println("after removing 0's -"+s.replaceFirst(removeString,""));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regex or external library.
You can do with "for":

```
String input="0000008008451"
String output = input.trim();
for( ;output.length() > 1 && output.charAt(0) == '0'; output = output.substring(1));

System.out.println(output);//8008451
```

Comment: Too many `String` generated during this loop... if there is 1000 `0` ...

Answer (score 0):

I made some benchmark tests and found, that the fastest way (by far) is this solution:

```
    private static String removeLeadingZeros(String s) {
      try {
          Integer intVal = Integer.parseInt(s);
          s = intVal.toString();
      } catch (Exception ex) {
          // whatever
      }
      return s;
    }
```

Especially regular expressions are very slow in a long iteration. (I needed to find out the fastest way for a batchjob.)

Comment: This doesn't work for alphanumerics, but it does work for my uses.

Answer (score -2):

And what about just searching for the first non-zero character?

```
[1-9]\d+
```

This regex finds the first digit between 1 and 9 followed by any number of digits, so for **"00012345"** it returns **"12345"**.
It can be easily adapted for alphanumeric strings.

Comment: This will not allow zero afterwards as well.

Answer (score -2):

```js
  const removeFirstZero = (ele) => parseInt(ele).toString()
  
  console.log('raw ' + '0776211121')
  console.log('removedZero ' + removeFirstZero('0776211121'))
```

Comment: That does not answer the question, because it does not work if the input contains other characters.

Comment: The question was asked about Java (refer to question tags), also the answer expected shall be covering all the cases and not just one particular case. Also, check if the question has been already answered.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).