# Remove leading zeros with regex but keep minus-sign

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace leading zeros in java with this expression found on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800739/remove-leading-zeros-from-alphanumeic-text):

`s.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "")`

But how can I make it work for values like `-00.8899`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try with:

```
String output = "-00.8899".replace("^(-?)0*", "$1");
```

Output:

```
-.8899
```

Comment: Hi..Nice solution. But I also want "+" sign before positive numbers. e.g, Double 0.10 should be +.10 and -0.10 should be -.10 and 1.0 should be +1.Please provide solution for this.

Comment: @AndiM Just try with: `^([-+]?)0*`

Answer (score 5):

Why are you dealing with a numeric value in a string variable?

Java being a strongly-typed language, you would probably have an easier time converting that to a float or double, then doing all the business logic, then finally formatting the output.

Something like:

```
Double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
double val = d; //mind the auto-boxing/unboxing

//business logic   

//get ready to display to the user
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0000");
String s = df.format(d);
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html