# Remove leading zeros with regex but keep minus-sign at JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Does someone have an idea how to remove leading zeros with regex but keen minus sign?

It so easy to do that for positive values

```
.replace(/^0+/,'')
```

but I absolutely have no idea how to do that in negative case, for example

from **-0.05** value to be **-.05**
from **-02.05** value to be **-2.05**

I have created [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vs7xe/) for clarity

Comment: Why not avoid regular expressions, and simply use [`parseFloat()`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vs7xe/2/)?

Comment: @David that would give `0.05` instead of `.05`

Comment: Also, if this is currency, there might be some rounding errors that mess up display when it's converted back to a string.

Comment: @Christoph: good point, I was focusing (only) on the second example.

Comment: @Dadiv, Christoph is right, just checked at jsfiddle. result -0.05

Comment: Search for [Remove leading zeros with regex but keep minus-sign](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907497/remove-leading-zeros-with-regex-but-keep-minus-sign?rq=1).

Comment: @MikeM, I have to agree with that. This is not a difficult problem at all, and it's now in my top-5 scoring answers in less than 15 min...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Capture the negative sign and include it in the replacement:

```
n_string.replace(/^(-?)0+/,'$1');
```

Answer (score 3):

The following could also do the job, in additional, it will allow you to have a 0 before .

```
n_string.replace(/^(-)?0+(?=\d)/,'$1');
```