# Java. Idiosyncratic output from modulo operator

Tags: java

I understand this:

`35%10` returns `5`

but, why does `000000035%10` return `9`?

Ruby does the same thing. I checked with irb.

Should I strip the 0s that are padding the number? What is the java function to do that?

Comment: Because it's an octal for 29 in decimal.

Comment: I have some ints in this variable that begin with the zeros like that and others that don't. They're all just decimal integers, and none should be octal. How do I make sure every integer is treated as decimal?

Comment: You need octal digits (0..7) to make an octal literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put the leading zeros followed by octal digits (from `0` to `7`), you're creating an [octal literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1). And since `000000035` in octal is `29` in decimal, its remainder with `10` is `9`.

**UPDATE**

If you have your "octal literal" in a string, simply use [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) and you'll get it parsed as a decimal.

```
assert Integer.parseInt("035") == 35;
```

Comment: I understand. And thank you. But I want any integer I have, such as "000030" or "000123" to have no zeros in it before I process it. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Just don't use leading zeros.

Comment: The integers are generated from really basic OCR code. That means that sometimes the generated numbers have leading zeros. That's just the way it is now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800739/how-to-remove-leading-zeros-from-alphanumeric-text  this question shows how to use regex to remove them.

Comment: You can simply use [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)). By default it parses decimals.

Comment: I have to convert it to a string first.
`accountIntArray[i] = Integer.parseInt( Integer.toString(accountNumber))%10;`isn't doing what I need...

Comment: I completely rewrote everything, and eventually got it to work with your help.

Answer (score 3):

Leading zero in number literal means octal number.

```
000000035 = 035 = 3*8 + 5 = 29
29 % 10 = 9
```

See [this page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Literals/Numeric_Literals/Integer_Literals) for other available formats.

Comment: That's weird why does it do that?

Comment: Sometimes it's convenient to specify constants in formats that are close to internal CPU representation.

Comment: Ya I guess I meant why does it differ from binary where you precede it by 0b00035 or hex where its 0x00035? That seems like a better system for avoiding confusions like this.