# compare two numeric String values

Tags: java

I have a simple doubt. Would be great if anyone helps me.

I have two strings:

```
String string1 = "4"; // and 
String string2 = "04";
```

Both the values are equal but how to compare them in java? We have `equals` and `equalsIgnoreCase` for comparing String alpha values, similarly how to compare numeric values.

Comment: new Integer( string1 ) == new Integer(string 2)

Comment: @madhairsilence. Note that your method will fail, as you are comparing two `Integer` objects using `==`, which might be considered a Crime.

Comment: @RohitJain please note that integers created by `new` are not 'cached'. `Integer a = 1;` is not the same as `Integer a = new Integer(1);`

Comment: @msi. Oouch. Didn't notice that.

Comment: @RohitJain
1. I gave an idea!! Thats why I commented not made an answer
2. What do u mean by Cache?? - Plz Explain
3. What is the crime in comparing with ==

Comment: @madhairsilence. 2. Java Caches the Integer objects in a certain range, which is generally `[-128, 127]`, in which case, it will not create a new Integer object when you assign an integer literal to an Integer reference, as stated by `msi`. I was mistaken, Cache doesn't hold tru in your case.

Comment: @madhairsilence. 3. Crime with object comparison with `==` is that, it doesn't really compares the content, rather the value of reference. So, two object reference pointing to two objects having same value will not be judged equal by `==`, so you should always use `equals` method for object comparison.

Comment: @RohitJain yeh correct! dnt notice dat!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
Integer.parseInt("4") == Integer.parseInt("04")
```

That is it. You can convert a numeric string into integer using [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) method, which returns an `int` type. And then comparison is same as `4 == 4`.

Comment: Wouldn't this overflow if the numbers are long than what Int can hold

Answer (score 16):

Don't forget the `BigInteger` for very long values.

```java
return new BigInteger(s1).compareTo(new BigInteger(s2));
```

Answer (score 10):

```
Integer.valueOf(string1).equals(Integer.valueOf(string2));
```

Comment: `valueOf(String)` internally calls `parseInt(String)` and wraps it. Comparing the results of  `parseInt(String)` using `==` works without boxing.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Integer class to convert the strings to integers.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29

```
Integer.parseInt(string1) == Integer.parseInt(string2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Skipping parsing it to an int at all to handle arbitrarily large numbers, only comparing the strings. As a bonus it also works for decimal numbers (unless there are trailing zeroes, where you probably can do similar thing with anchoring end of string instead).

You can omitt the trim if you are sure there are no whitespace characters

```
    String string1 = "4"; // and
    String string2 = "04";

    String noLeadingZeroes1 = string1.trim().replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");
    String noLeadingZeroes2 = string2.trim().replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");

    System.out.println(noLeadingZeroes1.equals(noLeadingZeroes2));
```

Comment: I also found this answer's explanation very helpful.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2800839/3966480

The ^ anchor will make sure that the 0+ being matched is at the beginning of the input. The (?!$) negative lookahead ensures that not the entire string will be matched.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison happens on chacracter basis. so '2' > '12' is true because the comparison will happen as '2' > '1' and in alphabetical way '2' is always greater than '1' as unicode. SO it will comeout true.

Answer (score -1):

if(String.valueOf(S1).compareTo(String.valueOf(S2)) < 0)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).