# How to remove leading zeros from numeric text?

Tags: java

I am using this to remove leading zeros from my input string.

```
return a.replaceAll("^0+","");
```

But the above string even removes from any string which is alphanumeric as well. I do not want to do that. My requirement is:

Only the leading zeros of numeric numbers should be removed e.g.

```
00002827393 -> 2827393
```

If you have a alpha numeric number the leading zeros must not be removed e.g.

```
000ZZ12340 -> 000ZZ12340
```

Comment: @syb0rg That's not quite the same. In that post zeros were removed from all alphanumeric strings. Here they're only removed from numbers.

Comment: Clarification Requested: Alphanumeric characters can be anywhere in string or just after leading zeros?

Comment: @Harish You are not able to find an answer for this question till now?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800739/how-to-remove-leading-zeros-from-alphanumeric-text)

Answer (score 10):

You can check if your string is only composed of digits first :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\d+$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(a);

if(m.matches()){
  return a.replaceAll("^0+", "");
} else {
  return a;
}
```

Also :

- consider making your pattern static, that way it will only be created once
- you may want to isolate the part with the matcher in a smaller function, "isOnlyDigit" for example

Answer (score 7):

You can also try this:

```
a.replaceAll("^0+(?=\\d+$)", "")
```

Notice that the positive lookahead `(?=\\d+$)` checks to see that the rest of the string (after the starting `0`s, matched by `^0+`) is composed of only digits before matching/replacing anything.

---

```
System.out.println("00002827393".replaceAll("^0+(?=\\d+$)", ""));
System.out.println("000ZZ12340".replaceAll("^0+(?=\\d+$)", ""));
```

```
2827393
000ZZ12340
```

Comment: That is some scarey looking regex

Comment: @MikeRylander: No, [this](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) is a scary looking regex.

Comment: @ColinDeClue Oh Dear God, WHY!

Answer (score 4):

Test if the incoming string matches the numeric pattern "\d+".  "\d" is the [character class for digits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).  If it's numeric, then return the result of the call to `replaceAll`, else just return the original string.

```
if (str.matches("\\d+"))
    return str.replaceAll("^0+", "");
return str;
```

Testing:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
   System.out.println(replaceNumZeroes("0002827393"));
   System.out.println(replaceNumZeroes("000ZZ1234566"));
}
```

yields the output

```
2827393
000ZZ1234566
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic:
it will convert the string to char array and start from i=0; As soon as it hits the first the first numeric value it breaks from the for loop and as soon as it hits first character (other than 1 to 9) it returns the same string. After the first for loop we have following cases to consider:

```
case 1. 00000000000
case 2. 00000011111
case 3. 11111111111
```

if it's 1 or 3 (i.e. the i's value from the first for loop will be 0 or length of the string )case then just return the string. Else for the 2nd case copy from the char array to a new char array starting for the i's value (i's value we will get from the first for loop and it holds the first numeric value position.). Hope it clears.
[image]

```
    public String trimLeadingZeros(String str)
    {
    if (str == null)
    {
        return null; //if null return null
    }
    char[] c = str.toCharArray();
    int i = 0;

    for(; i<c.length; i++)
    {
        if(c[i]=='0')
        {
           continue; 
        }
        else if(c[i]>='1' && c[i]<='9')
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            return str;
        }
    }
    if(i==0 || i==c.length)
    {
        return str;
    }
    else
    {
        char[] temp = new char[c.length-i];
        int index = 0;
        for(int j=i; j<c.length; j++)
        {
            temp[index++] = c[j];
        }
        return new String(temp);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply I did the following

```
String string = string.trim();
while(string.charAt(0) == '0'){
    string = string.substring(1);
}
```

Comment: 1. You missed the part that "If you have a alpha numeric number the leading zeros must not be removed".  
2. If your string have 20 leading zeros, you will create 20 strings that needs to be garbage collected.