# String function to accept the 10 digit mobile no. , discards any no. less than 10 digits, trims zeroes at the beginning

Tags: java

When we enter a no like "00982787878" (having 9 digits and zeros) the output should not be   displayed after the zeros are trimmed.

### Problem:

There is some problem in while loop as the output is a number with just one 0 trimmed.

### Code:

```
public static String trimZeros(String mobNumber)
{
        boolean exitLoop = true;
        int count = 0;


        while (exitLoop && mobNumber.substring(count) == "0") 
            mobNumber = mobNumber.substring(0);
        
        if (mobNumber.charAt(count) != '0')
        {
            exitLoop = false;
        }
        count++;
        mobNumber = mobNumber.replaceAll(" ", "");
        mobNumber = mobNumber.length() < 10 ? mobNumber.substring(mobNumber
                .length()) : mobNumber.substring(mobNumber.length() - 10);
        
        return mobNumber;
}
```

Comment: So, do you have a question?

Comment: Why are you removing digits from a phone number? That doesn't make sense - you're changing the number.

Comment: Don't compare Strings with ==

Comment: Whats the problem you are facing here

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: i just want to remove zeros at the beginning, if the no. remaining after removing zeroes is less than 10 digits then it should not display anything...just blank.
and if the no. is greater than 10 digits, it should display the last 10 digits BUT WITHOUT ZEROES IN THE BEGINNNG

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889853/how-to-remove-leading-zeros-from-numeric-text

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your problem:

```
public static String trimZeros(String number) {

    //trim zeros at left
    number = number.replaceAll("^0*", "");

    //if the length is < 10, returns an empty string
    if (number.length() < 10) {
        return "";
    }

    //if the length is > 10, trims any number at left
    if (number.length() > 10) {
        number = number.replaceAll(".*(\\d{10})$", "$1");
    }

    return number;
}
```

Comment: NO, it should not throw any exception, it should just not display anything.
also, what if the no. is greater than 10

Comment: @hotshot02 So just replace the `throw` with `return "";` then? Also, `!= 10` covers numbers that are both shorter and longer than 10 digits. I still don't understand what purpose mangling the phone number serves thought.