# Removing leading zero in java code

Tags: java

May I know how can I remove the leading zero in JAVA code? I tried several methods like regex tools

```
"s.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "") / replaceAll("^0*", "");`
```

but it's seem like not support with my current compiler compliance level (1.3), will have a red line stated the method replaceFirst(String,String)is undefined for the type String.

### Part of My Java code

```
public String proc_MODEL(Element recElement)
{
 String SEAT        = "";
    try
    {
        SEAT    = setNullToString(recElement.getChildText("SEAT")); // xml value =0000500

       if (SEAT.length()>0)  
       {
           SEAT = SEAT.replaceFirst("^0*", "");  //I need to remove leading zero to only 500 
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
           return "501 Exception in proc_MODEL";
       }
    } 
}
```

Appreciate for help.

Comment: Totally out of curiosity, why Java 1.3? Is this on an embedded system or something? That is _ooooold_ by Java standards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove leading zeros from alphanumeric text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800739/how-to-remove-leading-zeros-from-alphanumeric-text)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want remove leading zeros, you could parse to an `Integer` and convert back to a `String` with one line like

```
String seat = "001";// setNullToString(recElement.getChildText("SEAT"));
seat = Integer.valueOf(seat).toString();
System.out.println(seat);
```

Output is

```
1
```

Of course if you intend to use the value it's probably better to keep the `int`

```
int s = Integer.parseInt(seat);
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Thousand of thanks to you @Elliot. This method is much easy and efficient.

Answer (score 3):

`replaceFirst()` was introduced in 1.4 and your compiler pre-dates that.

One possibility is to use something like:

```
public class testprog {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "0001000";
        while ((s.length() > 1) && (s.charAt(0) == '0'))
            s = s.substring(1);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

It's not the most efficient code in the world but it'll get the job done.

A more efficient segment without unnecessary string creation could be:

```
public class testprog {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "0001000";
        int pos = 0;
        int len = s.length();
        while ((pos < len-1) && (s.charAt(pos) == '0'))
            pos++;
        s = s.substring(pos);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Both of those also handle the degenerate cases of an empty string and a string containing *only* `0` characters.

Comment: Nice, Both acceptable too !! Thanks for the solution !!

Answer (score 1):

Using a java method `str.replaceAll("^0+(?!$)", "")` would be simple;

`First parameter`:regex -- the regular expression to which this string is to be matched.

`Second parameter`: replacement -- the string which would replace matched expression.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in Java documentation, 'replaceFirst' only started existing since Java 1.4 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Use this function instead:

```
String removeLeadingZeros(String str) {
  while (str.indexOf("0")==0)
    str = str.substring(1);
  return str;
}
```

Comment: it's the same like using replaceFirst("^0*",""), the whole string is gone in that case