# Java : BigDecimal - Print the number has input

Tags: java, math, bigdecimal, zero

I am trying to print the BigDecimal in the given input format,but its pre-pending a zero before decimal point.

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(.356);
System.out.println(bd);
```

Output : `0.356`

Excepted Output : `.356`

Comment: Why is that expected?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800739/how-to-remove-leading-zeros-from-alphanumeric-text

Comment: its one of the test case so

Answer (score 2):

Use `DecimalFormat` to suppress the leading zeros such as:

```
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    import java.math.*;

    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecmial(.925);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.000");
    System.out.println(df.format(bd)); // .925
```