# Javascript - Remove all char '0' that come before another char

Tags: javascript

**I have many strings like this:**

`0001, 0002, ..., 0010, 0011, ..., 0100, 0101,...`

**I would like these to become like this:**

`1, 2, ..., 10, 11, ..., 100, 101, ...`

So I would like to remove all the `0` chars before a different char is present.
I tried with

```
.replace(/0/g, '')
```

But of course then it also removes the `0` chars after. Therefore for example `0010` becomes `1` instead of `10`. Can you please help me?

Comment: Is it array? or String?

Comment: For individual strings now deleted answer would be better: `parseInt('000101').toString()`.

Comment: Can you confirm there won't be dots, spaces, etc. in your numbers ? Do your strings contain one or several comma separated numbers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
.replace(/\d+/g, function(v){ return +v })
```

Comment: `'010004'.replace(/0+([1-9]+)/g,'$1')`?

Comment: @ArunPJohny You're right. I edited with a lazy but reliable solution

Answer (score 2):

This is the shortes Solution

```js
"0001".replace(/^0+/,""); // => 1 
...
// Tested on Win7 Chrome 44+
```

`^`  ... starting of the String
`0+` ... At least one `0`

P.s.: test Regex on pages likes: https://regex101.com/ or https://www.debuggex.com

**Update 1:**

For one long String

```js
 "0001, 0002, 0010, 0011, 0100, 0101".replace(/(^|\s)0+/g,"") // => 1, 2, 10, 11, 100, 101
 // Tested on Win7 Chrome 44+
```

**Examples:**

```js
//  short Strings
var values = ['0001', '0002','0010', '0011','0100','0101'];
for(var idx in values){
  document.write(values[idx] + " -> "+values[idx].replace(/^0+/,"") + "<br/>");
}

// one long String 
document.write("0001, 0002, 0010, 0011, 0100, 0101".replace(/(^|\s)0+/g,""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex as `/(^|,\s*)0+/g` it will select 0's at beginning or followed by `,` and space

```js
document.write('0001, 0002, ..., 0010, 0011, ..., 0100, 0101,...'.replace(/(^|,\s*)0+/g,'$1'))
```

**Explanation :**

```
(^|,\s*)0+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/nS4qZ3O12XsyfSYb)

Answer (score 1):

Previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800739/how-to-remove-leading-zeros-from-alphanumeric-text).

```
.replace(/^0+(?!$)/, '')
```

Functionally the same as winner_joiner's answer, with the exception that this particular regex won't return a completely empty string should the input consist entirely of zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

var text='00101';
var result=parseInt(text);