# How to disable entering numbers after zero in edittext?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext

How to disable numbers entering after zero in edittext?

I have validated only for this..

```
 if (TextUtils.isEmpty(strBalance)) {
                    Toast.makeText(TransactionSellINActivity.this, "Amount should not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else if (strBalance.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                    Toast.makeText(TransactionSellINActivity.this, "Amount should not be Zero", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
```

But if user enters 01 or 001 or 02,03 etc.,? ie number after zero? -> I want to restrict those numbers

How to handle such case?

Comment: you want 01 or 02 or you dont want 01 or 02 be clear..

Comment: I don't want to use

Comment: have you tried using methods like `startsWith` and `length`

Comment: i have updated the answer.

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800739/how-to-remove-leading-zeros-from-alphanumeric-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(strBalance)) {
                Toast.makeText(TransactionSellINActivity.this, "Amount should not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else if (strBalance.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                Toast.makeText(TransactionSellINActivity.this, "Amount should not be Zero", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            else if(strBalance.indexOf("0")!=a.length()-1)
                {
                Toast.makeText(TransactionSellINActivity.this, "Amount Not Valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(TransactionSellINActivity.this, "Amount  Valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                }
```

Comment: This will not ptint number after 0.

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to restrict those numbers that are starting with 0. For this you have to use `.startsWith()`

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(strBalance)) {
                Toast.makeText(TransactionSellINActivity.this, "Amount should not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else if (strBalance.startsWith("0")) {
                Toast.makeText(TransactionSellINActivity.this, "Amount should not be Zero", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

**User can't add numbers after zero using this code TRY IT**

```
Edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

            if (Edittext.getText().toString().startsWith("0")
                    && Edittext.getText().length() > 1) {

                Edittext.setText("0");
                Edittext.setSelection(Edittext.getText().toString().length());
            }
        }
    });
```

May be useful to you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
private EditText  mEt;//your edittext
private TextWatcher mMoneyWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        if (!s.toString.isEmpty()) {
            mPayEtValue.removeTextChangedListener(mMoneyWatcher);
            if (s.toString.charAt(0)=='0') {
              mEt.setText(s.toString.substring(1,s.length()));  
            }

            mEt.addTextChangedListener(mMoneyWatcher);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};
mEt.addTextChangedListener(mMoneyWatcher);
```

Comment: what is mPayEtValue?

Comment: @Walter sorry my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can do this too, let user enter zeros as many as he want. Following regex will remove leading zeros from string after then you can proceed with your string.

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(strBalance) && Integer.parseInt(strBalance) > 0) 
{
        strBalance=strBalance.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "")       
}
```