# Simplifying conditional logic for readibility

Tags: java

I have following code that sets `vrstaProizvoda`.

```
private String napraviVrstuProizvoda(String kreditJeAktivanKod, String idArmPlana) {
    String vrstaProizvoda = null;
    if (kreditJeAktivanKod != null && kreditJeAktivanKod.equals("Y")) {
        vrstaProizvoda = VrstaProizvoda.STEP.value();
    } else if (idArmPlana != null && !idArmPlana.isEmpty() && !idArmPlana.equals("0000")){
        vrstaProizvoda = VrstaProizvoda.ARM.value();
    }
    return vrstaProizvoda;

}
```

Looking at `else if` statement, everything is negating values. Is there a better way to write `idArmPlana` condition so it is easier to read? Or is it not worth it?

Comment: `if (kreditJeAktivanKod != null && kreditJeAktivanKod.equals("Y"))` can be rewritten as `if ("Y".equals(kreditJeAktivanKod))`

Comment: please go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write something along the lines of:

```java
!(idArmPlana == null || idArmPlana.isEmpty() || idArmPlana.equals("0000"))
```

The logic is still the same, but it is slightly more readable. Having long chains of and's or or's is never *super* readable, but doing something like this where you have your simple conditions, or them together, then negate the result can work.

Comment: This is an application of *DeMorgan's Law*.

Answer (score 2):

To make it easier to read, just create small functions that have a logical name:

```
private String napraviVrstuProizvoda(String kreditJeAktivanKod, String idArmPlana) {
    String vrstaProizvoda = null;
    if (isYes(kreditJeAktivanKod)) {
        vrstaProizvoda = VrstaProizvoda.STEP.value();
    } else if (!isZero(idArmPlana)){
        vrstaProizvoda = VrstaProizvoda.ARM.value();
    }
    return vrstaProizvoda;

}

function boolean isYes(String string){
  return (null != string && string.equals("Y");
}

function boolean isZero(String string){
 return (null != string && !string.isEmpty() && string.equals("0000");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure about `Arrays.asList`, but the recurring `idArmPlana` could be used just once:

```
return "Y".equals(kreditJeAktivanKod)
        ? VrstaProizvoda.STEP.value()
        : !Arrays.<String>asList("", "0000", null).contains(idArmPlana)
        ? VrstaProizvoda.ARM.value()
        : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Apache commons-lang3 library you can:

```
import org.apache.commns.lang3.StringUtils;

if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(StringUtils.stripStart(idArmPlana,"0")))
```

`stripStart` stolen from [How to remove leading zeros from alphanumeric text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800739/how-to-remove-leading-zeros-from-alphanumeric-text)

Answer (score 1):

My preference is one of these:

```
private String napraviVrstuProizvoda(String kreditJeAktivanKod, String idArmPlana) {
    if ( (kreditJeAktivanKod != null) && kreditJeAktivanKod.equals("Y") ) {
        return VrstaProizvoda.STEP.value();
    } else if ( (idArmPlana != null) && !idArmPlana.isEmpty() && !idArmPlana.equals("0000") ) {
        return VrstaProizvoda.ARM.value();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

private String napraviVrstuProizvoda(String kreditJeAktivanKod, String idArmPlana) {
    if ( strEquals(kreditJeAktivanKod, "Y") ) {
        return VrstaProizvoda.STEP.value();
    } else if ( !strIsEmpty(idArmPlana) && !strEquals(idArmPlana, "0000") ) {
        return VrstaProizvoda.ARM.value();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here are a number of rewrites to show a range of alternatives, and to show how to reach the above with incremental adjustments:

Rewritten with more spaces and parenthesis.  This makes it easier to pick out the long variable names, and relieves the reader of all need to organize the expression logic:

```
private String napraviVrstuProizvoda(String kreditJeAktivanKod, String idArmPlana) {
    String vrstaProizvoda = null;
    if ( (kreditJeAktivanKod != null) && kreditJeAktivanKod.equals("Y") ) {
        vrstaProizvoda = VrstaProizvoda.STEP.value();
    } else if ( (idArmPlana != null) && !idArmPlana.isEmpty() && !idArmPlana.equals("0000") ) {
        vrstaProizvoda = VrstaProizvoda.ARM.value();
    }
    return vrstaProizvoda;
}
```

Rewritten to remove the default 'null' value.  Having such a value is problematic.  Consider if the logic were much more complex.  Having a default value takes away the opportunity for the compiler to detect unhandled cases.

```
private String napraviVrstuProizvoda(String kreditJeAktivanKod, String idArmPlana) {
    String vrstaProizvoda;
    if ( (kreditJeAktivanKod != null) && kreditJeAktivanKod.equals("Y") ) {
        vrstaProizvoda = VrstaProizvoda.STEP.value();
    } else if ( (idArmPlana != null) && !idArmPlana.isEmpty() && !idArmPlana.equals("0000") ) {
        vrstaProizvoda = VrstaProizvoda.ARM.value();
    } else {
        vrstaProizvoda = null;
    }
    return vrstaProizvoda;
}
```

Rewritten with multiple return values.  This is my preference, but some prefer a single return statement, as was present in the original method.

```
private String napraviVrstuProizvoda(String kreditJeAktivanKod, String idArmPlana) {
    if ( (kreditJeAktivanKod != null) && kreditJeAktivanKod.equals("Y") ) {
        return VrstaProizvoda.STEP.value();
    } else if ( (idArmPlana != null) && !idArmPlana.isEmpty() && !idArmPlana.equals("0000") ) {
        return VrstaProizvoda.ARM.value();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Rewritten, with helper methods (see below).  This is a little clearer, but at a cost of obscuring the test logic.  Splitting code into a lot of small methods, while often encouraged, is not always preferred in practice.

```
private String napraviVrstuProizvoda(String kreditJeAktivanKod, String idArmPlana) {
    if ( strEquals(kreditJeAktivanKod, "Y") ) {
        return VrstaProizvoda.STEP.value();
    } else if ( !strIsEmpty(idArmPlana) && !strEquals(idArmPlana, "0000") ) {
        return VrstaProizvoda.STEP.value();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Helper methods:

```
// Test that two strings are equal.  Handle null values.
private boolean strEquals(String value1, String value2) {
    if ( value1 == null ) {
        return ( value2 == null );
    } else if ( value2 == null ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return value1.equals(value2);
    }
}

// Test that two strings are equal.  Handle null values.
private boolean strEquals(String value1, String value2) {
    boolean result;
    if ( value1 == null ) {
        result = ( value2 == null );
    } else if ( value2 == null ) {
        result = false;
    } else {
        result = value1.equals(value2);
    }
    return result;
}

// Test if a string is neither null nor empty.
private boolean strIsNotEmpty(String value) {
    return ( (value != null) && !value.isEmpty() );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add one more alternative to the already given good answers:

```
private String napraviVrstuProizvoda(String kreditJeAktivanKod, String idArmPlana) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(kreditJeAktivanKod).filter(e->e.equals("Y"))
           .isPresent()? VrstaProizvoda.STEP.value() :
           Optional.ofNullable(idArmPlana).filter(e->!e.equals("0000")).filter(e->!e.isEmpty())
           .isPresent()? VrstaProizvoda.ARM.value(): 
            null;
}
```